# battery receiver fully charged doesnt work

Tags: java, android, battery

I found that in the manifest can not be registered (intent-filter battery low, battery changed).
 I need to get the notification when the battery is fully charged. when I have a running app so it is working, but when I close the application so it does not work.
 I need the receiver to run in the background when the application is closed.

```
Main.class

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
mContext.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver,filter);

private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
        ...
        }
```

Comment: In which programming language did you implement the code?

Comment: java language(android)