# How to make android start my application automatically when battery is fully charged?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, batterymanager, sticky-broadcast

My question is similar to this one:
[battery receiver fully charged doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045625/battery-receiver-fully-charged-doesnt-work)
. That question has no answers.

Here are the approaches I have thought of so far:

Approach 1: Register a BroadcastReceiver in the AndroidManifest.xml for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.

This won't work because of the following reason:

I cannot register a BroadcastReceiver in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to listen for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` because it is a Sticky Intent as stated here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.

Approach 2: Register a BroadcastReceiver programatically in the MainActivity.java's `onCreate()` method.

Issue with this approach is : [Avoid registering duplicate broadcast receivers in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414410/avoid-registering-duplicate-broadcast-receivers-in-android)

In addition to the above issue, I do not understand the scope of broadcast receivers properly. To be more precise, I don't understand what happens to the broadcast receivers that an app has registered when the app is:

1) Destroyed by the Android system by calling it's `onDestroy()` method

2) When the app is force stopped by the user via the Application Manager setting.

Could someone please explain it please?

Approach 3: Use a work around that uses SharedPreferences and a BroadcastReceiver for listening to device reboot.

Have a shared preference that let's me know if I have previously registered a broadcast receiver for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. If yes, don't create a new one, else, create a new broadcast receiver for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. As pointed out in the link in Approach 2, the value in the SharedPreference becomes invalid upon device reboot, so have a separate broadcast receiver to create the receiver again on reboot and update the shared preferences to reflect the same.

Although, approach 3 may work, I feel it is a cumbersome way. Is there a simpler approach?

Additionally, my application will be inefficient since it is going to run for every change in battery state. Is there a way to make it run, only when the battery is full, which is my main purpose?